# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I read through the the other topics on the same issue, but not sure that i should work off an inctance, in my instance.

i have the following:

```
public interface ITrainingService : IDependency
{
   void ResetModule(int id, int userScormModuleId, int currentUser);
}

public class TrainingService : ITrainingService
{
 public void ResetModule(int id, int userScormModuleId, int currentUser)
 {
   Zinc.Repositories.Scorm.IScormModuleRepository.ResetModule(id, userScormModuleId, currentUser);  //i get the error here
 }
}
```

ResetModule is contained in:

```
public class ScormModuleRepository : Repository<ScormModule>, IScormModuleRepository
{
   public void ResetModule(int id, int userScormModuleId, int currentUser)
   {
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ZincModelContainer.CONNECTIONSTRING))
     {
         using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
         {
           conn.Open();
           cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           cmd.CommandText = "[Zinc].[ResetUserScormModuleData]";

           SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@userId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
           param.Value = id;
           cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

           SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@userScormModuleId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
           param2.Value = userScormModuleId;
           cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

           SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@currentUser", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
           param3.Value = currentUser;
           cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);

           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
     }
  }
}
 public interface IScormModuleRepository : IRepository<ScormModule>
 {
   void ResetModule(int id, int userScormModuleId, int currentUser);
 }
```

the whole error:  Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Zinc.Repositories.Scorm.IScormModuleRepository.ResetModule(int, int, int)'   C:\TFSPreview\Zinc\Project\ServiceImplementations\TrainingService.cs    501 8   Zinc

i dont understand? how must i work from an instance? or what must i instantiate or is my problem of another nature?

thanks

Comment: You might be calling the non static method from a static method. Is that so?

Comment: What *do* you understand about the difference between static and instance members? You're trying to invoke an *instance* method without having an instance. Basically your `TrainingService` should have a reference to an instance of `ScormModuleRepository` by the looks of it.

Comment: What's `Zinc`? What's `Zinc.Repositories`? What's `Zinc.Repositories.Scorm.IScormModuleRepository`?

Comment: @Sandeep: Whether it's from a static method or not makes no difference. All that's important is that he's trying to call an instance method *without a reference to call it on*.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Open your eyes. `IScormModuleRepository` is defined in his code.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Thank you very much for being so exemplary polite.

Comment: Please all bear with me, I am new to all this and working on a complicated big system. I am learning as I go along. @Jon Skeet: with regards to "Basically your TrainingService should have a reference to an instance of ScormModuleRepository" I unserstand this is what i need, thank you but how do i create this reference? I will go read up instance and static members :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an instance of a class implementing `IScormModuleRepository`. With your code, what method should be called? `IScormModuleRepository` is an interface, it doesn't even contain an implementation of the method you are trying to call...

You need something like this:

```
public class TrainingService : ITrainingService
{
    IScormModuleRepository _repository;

    public TrainingService(IScormModuleRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public void ResetModule(int id, int userScormModuleId, int currentUser)
    {
        _repository.ResetModule(id, userScormModuleId, currentUser);
    }
}
```

You now can use your `TrainingService` like this:

```
var repository = new ScormModuleRepository(...);
var trainingService = new TrainingService(repository);
trainingService.ResetModule(...);
```

Comment: i want to call ResetModule which is in ScormModuleRepository i posted it in my OP in the second block of code :) please see OP, thanks

Comment: @charlie_cat: I know that. Please see update on how to use the class I posted.